# import google fonts on bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, fonts

I'm trying to import google fonts, the thing is i follow the steps and actuallyit works if a use

```
<h3 style="color:white ; font-family:signika; padding:2%"> Whatever </h3>
```

but what i want to do it's set the Signika font as the default one, so i do

```
html {

font-family: 'Signika', 'Signika:700' , sans-serif;
-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
```

but it does not wor,i still have to set it in every html tag,  i even tried to put it specificly like

```
h1 {
margin: .67em 0;
font-size: 2em;
font-family:'Signika';
}
```

but still, not working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out i was putting the rule font-family in h1 but that was not the only instance of h1, therefor i had to look further and i found the respective h1 sentence to use the font-family, so it was missplaced after all, thank you for you help, was very useful!

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to your index.html file in the `<header>`

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Signika' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Answer (score 1):

If `font-family: signika` works inline use that in the css file too.

```
html {
    font-family: signika, sans-serif;
}
```

The rule `'Signika:700'` would not do anything, what I think you're trying to do should be written as:

```
font-family: signika;
font-weight: 700;
```